# Guardar ID mayor a 20 caracteres

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

Estoy haciendo un login con Gmail y al obtener los datos del usuario, debo guardar los mismo en una base de datos.

Así esta estructurada la base de datos.

Base de datos

```
id (bigint)
userid (bigint)
name (varchar 50)
correo (varchar 100)
```

El id de Gmail seria así: `111119672000055500000`

El problema es que en la base de datos no me deja guardar el id de Gmail, y este es el error de arroja cuando lo quiero hacer de forma manual:

> 1 fila afectada.
> Warning: #1264 Out of range value for column 'userid' at row 1

Agradezco la ayuda de antemano

Comment: aunque es un numero me parece que lo deberias guardar como un varchar

Comment: El tema es que ese número que muestras es demaciado grande para un bigint el maximo que soporta es el siguiente 9223372036854775807, dado el tamaño tendrias que manejarlo como un varchar

Comment: Gracias... entonces dentro de mysql no hay forma de guardarlo así. Debería guardarlos como texto y después pasarlo como entero, no?

Comment: Para qué necesitas que sea un entero? Vas a sumarle o restarle algo? Así sea un conjunto de caracteres numéricos, no vas a operar con él matemáticamente; por eso te dicen todos que es un varchar (una cadena de caracteres) asimilable a un String sin más. Como te respondieron, ni un bigint te da el espacio suficiente. Si ese campo es un índice, revisa cómo usar índices tipo varchar.

Answer (score 1):

No podrías guardarlo como número, deberías guardarlo como **texto** o **cadena** ya que incluso el valor mas grande que puedes almacenar en MySQL (en este caso con BigInt) va de -9.223.372.036.854.775.808 a 9.223.372.036.854.775.807 (19 dígitos) y el valor que quieres guardar es de 21 dígitos.